# Looking for the Mach-O loader source code in the Darwin sources

Tags: open-source, macos, loader, darwin

As I understand it, Mach-O should be part of the Darwin open source packages. Could someone please help me locate the loader? I've no idea where it is and where to download that code from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Mach-O is loaded by many components, e.g. the `dyld` for loading a dynamic library, the XNU kernel for loading into memory and run it, etc. Which part do you want?

But no matter which, you can find the latest source code in http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1063/.